# How can I access and change a field value of object-member inside a object in kotlin by reflection?

Tags: kotlin, reflection

For example, I want to access the property `age` using reflection from the Father object

```kotlin
data class Father(
   val children: Children()
)

data class Children(
   val age: Int
)
```

Comment: Why would you do this using reflection?

Comment: I want to use this solution in another project. Therefore I asked with this example because the idea is the same